# Power series examples with different properties

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to accumulate some examples of power series with certain properties according to an exercise in Abbott's analysis text. I'm having trouble developing examples for the following:

1) power series absolutely convergent on $[-1,1]$ and divergent elsewhere

2) converges conditionally at $-1$ and absolutely at $1$

3) converges conditionally at $-1$ and $1$

The ratio test seemed promising for $\#1$... Namely I thought I can find a series whose ratio limit is $<1$ at $x=1$ and $-1$, but this is difficult (easy to find series that diverge at those end points).

Examples and thoughts on creative strategies appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1)$ Try $\sum x^n/n^2$

$2)$ A power series takes the form $\sum a_n x^n$. If we have absolute convergence at $1$, then $\sum |a_n|$ is convergent. At $-1$, the series is $\sum (-1)^n a_n$, so it must converge absolutely. Thus, such an example doesn't exist.

$3)$ Consider $\sum a_n x^n$, where $a_n =0$ for odd $n$ and $a_n = (-1)^{n/2}/n$ for even $n$. The series is just $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{2k} x^{2k}$$

Comment: Can you suggest how to prove that #1 diverges outside [-1,1]? I'm trying to show that x^n/n^2 goes to infinity but this is surprisingly not obvious to prove...

Comment: @rorty you can use the ratio test to conclude that $R = 1$ is the radius of convergence, which gives the result directly